# Default created date (or any standard hidden field) on Web-to-Lead?

Tags: php, salesforce

I have created a web to lead form in sales force but I cannot seem to default standard fields such as `created date = d/m/Y`.like other field

`first_name, last_name, email, lead_source`

I want same field for created date

Comment: Can you provide a link where you have took reference from and what you have done. So it will be understandable

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=leads_fields.htm&language=en

Comment: $todayDate = date('d/m/Y'); $post_data=array();
                $post_data['first_name'] = $orderRow['first_name'];
                $post_data['last_name'] = $orderRow['last_name'];
                $post_data['email'] = $orderRow['email'];
                $post_data['city'] = $orderRow['city'];
                $post_data['company'] = $orderRow['company_name'];
                $post_data['lead_source'] = 'Website';
                $post_data['created_by'] = $todayDate;
                $post_data['state'] = $stateName['state_code'];

Comment: i used $post_data['created_by'] = $todayDate; but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to programmatically set the `Lead.CreatedDate`. This value is set automatically when the new `Lead` is created, regardless of the method (UI, Web-to-Lead, API, etc). The only way to have this field changed is via Salesforce support granting you "Create Audit Fields" permissions and then modifying the records via *Data Loader*, but you would have to make a compelling case for why it needs to be updated. Using a new custom field to store your desired date value is what I would recommend.

```
Lead.MyCreatedDate__c
```

See [Salesforce Answers](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gwOwAAI) for more info.

> It is possible, but you should talk to your System Administrator about the volume of records that you wish to update. This is only possible by submitting a case to Salesforce and requesting the "Create Audit Fields" permission. Then your system admin will take the records you want to update and change the created dates using the Data Loader.